# WSO2 NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: wso2

I am using wso2 API Manager. I published an API in WSO2 Store and created an application to test my API. when I call a service from API Console, the response that I receive is as below(my browser is firefox):

TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

I googled the problem but the proposed solutions are not applicable in WSO2. I would appreciate any help

Comment: Do you see any errors in the API Manager server logs? Also, try to use a different tool(CURL, Advanced REST client) to test the API and check the output.

Comment: Did you accept the certificate of the API Manager from your browser?